# Google Places SDK Usage limitation for iOS and Android

Tags: android, ios, iphone, google-maps, google-places-api

I need to use google place SDK for iOS and Android in bellow usage,

As per SDK page, there is limitation up to 1,50,000 per day once i enable billing,

my Query is How they are going to charge , Bellow are is the usage in my project

1) On every 5 minutes, I will call below API to get Place Id (288 per day)

https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/start

2) Then i need to get details of the place so i call below APi to get location details

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?placeid=ChIJjwYORsmEXjkRGepSMAs7Iis&key=AIzaSyCHRzGbKDDbmrjtxMX7o_qknP6-m46nvtQ

3) to download  location image in my local i call below API

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/photo?maxwidth=400&photoreference=PHOTOREFERENCE&key=AIzaSyCHRzGbKDDbmrjtxMX7o_qknP6-m46nvtQ

usage limit is 1,50,000 How they will check usage limit on above all three API calls, I had checked with bellow link but confuse on above three combination usage or separate usage limit?

https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/usage

Comment: Everything has changed. Google introduced Google Maps Platform with new pricing model. Have a look at documentation: https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/user-guide/pricing-changes/

Comment: Another useful link: https://developers.google.com/maps/billing/understanding-cost-of-use

Comment: How they calculate count of usage, like I am using three API to get place details so they will calculate 3 count of call on every usage or, single count on same google place API and i do practice this on every 5 minutes, so its calculate it as 3*5*12 = 175 call per hour for user AM i right ?

Comment: to get place_id from the gps location google places android sdk is not calculate in the count of usage ?

Comment: Google will calculate each request that you send to their servers. Also it looks like you are checking usage on Places API for Android, but you are using Places API web services in 2) and 3). These are different things. Check usage of Places API web service in your developer console.